# Getting ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence on a Python Script in the Field Calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, file-geodatabase, error-000539, error-000989

I have a script that populates a FacilityID Field on a Attribute table in the Field Calculator but when I run the script below I am getting a error.

Python Script:

```
def autoInc():

import arcpy, os
nullvalues = ["", " ", None, 0]
fac_id_values = []
# Loop through and get Max value
fc= r"c:\GIS\Nambe_Data\nambedatabase\Nambe_ExistingInfrastructureSurvey_v1x0.gdb\Co‌mmunicationInfrastructure\cTelcomLine"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['*']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        row_dict = dict(zip(cur.fields,row))
        facilityid = row_dict['FacilityID']
        if facilityid not in nullvalues:
            print facilityid
            fac_id_values.append(facilityid)
max_value = max(fac_id_values)
print max_value

# Loop through and Calculate new values
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Telecommunications Line")
for row in cur:
    max_value = max_value + 1
    if row.FACILITYID in nullvalues:
        row.FACILITYID = "COMLI1" + str(format(max_value,'04d'))
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Error I am getting is :

```
Messages
Executing: CalculateField "Communication\Telecommunications Line" FacilityID autoIncrement() PYTHON_9.3 "import arcpy\nnullvalues = ["", " ", None, 0]\n# Loop through and get Max value\ncur = arcpy.SearchCursor("Telecommunications Line")\nfac_id_values =     [int(row.FACILITYID[-4:]) for row in cur if row.FACILITYID not in nullvalues]\n\nmax_value = max(fac_id_values)\n\n# Loop through and Calculate new values\ncur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Telecommunications Line")\nfor row in cur:\n    max_value = max_value + 1\n    if row.FACILITYID in nullvalues:\n        row.FACILITYID = "COMLI1" + str(format(max_value,'04d'))\n        cur.updateRow(row)"
Start Time: Thu May 15 09:00:06 2014
ERROR 000539: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Failed to execute (CalculateField).
Failed at Thu May 15 09:00:06 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.13 seconds)
```

For this Line: max_value = max(fac_id_values)

New Error:
Messages

```
Executing: CalculateField "Communication\Telecommunications Line" FacilityID autoInc() PYTHON_9.3 "def autoInc():\n\nimport arcpy, os\nnullvalues = ["", " ", None, 0]\nfac_id_values = []\n# Loop through and get Max value\nfc= r"c:\GIS\Nambe_Data\nambedatabase\Nambe_ExistingInfrastructureSurvey_v1x0.gdb\Co‌mmunicationInfrastructure\cTelcomLine"\nwith arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['*']) as cur:\n    for row in cur:\n        row_dict = dict(zip(cur.fields,row))\n        facilityid = row_dict['FacilityID']\n        if facilityid not in nullvalues:\n            print facilityid\n            fac_id_values.append(facilityid)\nmax_value = max(fac_id_values)\nprint max_value\n\n# Loop through and Calculate new values\ncur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Telecommunications Line")\nfor row in cur:\n    max_value = max_value + 1\n    if row.FACILITYID in nullvalues:\n        row.FACILITYID = "COMLI1" + str(format(max_value,'04d'))\n        cur.updateRow(row)"
Start Time: Thu May 15 13:38:07 2014
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented     block (line 3)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
Failed at Thu May 15 13:38:07 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should get you to where you need to be.

```
import arcpy
nullvalues = ["", " ", None, 0]
fac_id_values = []
# Loop through and get Max value
fc= r"c:\GIS\Nambe_Data\nambedatabase\Nambe_ExistingInfrastructureSurvey_v1x0.gdb\Co‌mmunicationInfrastructure\cTelcomLine"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['FacilityID']) as cur:
    fac_id_values = [int(row[0][-4:]) for row in cur if row[0] not in nullvalues]

try:
    max_value = max(fac_id_values)
except:
    # Make an allowance for fac_id_values to be empty
    max_value = 0
    
# Loop through and Calculate new values
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['FacilityID']) as ucur:
    for row in ucur:
        if row[0] in nullvalues:
            max_value += 1
            row[0] = "COMLI1" + str(format(max_value,'04d'))
            ucur.updateRow(row)
```